# Mediawiki: configuring the entry page, adding a new page

Tags: mediawiki

Have a wiki installed in our organization, and want to start using it.

Failed to find the answers for the next 2 basic questions:

- How do I configure the entry page to show a list of all existing pages
- How do I create a new page (!). Only succeeded doing it by typing a url of an non existing page. Guess there are nicer methods for this

Thanks

Gidi

Comment: you may also find this proposal interesting: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia

Comment: It's better not to join 2 different questions in one entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For how to show a list of all pages, look at [DynamicPageList](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDynamicPageList_%28Wikimedia%29), which is part of MediaWiki. (There's a more advanced third-party version, but it's not needed for such a simple task.)

Creating a new page really is exactly as you said: Type a URL and save some edits. Most beginning editors will edit a link into a page, and then use that link to browse to the page, so that they don't accidentally forget the spelling and lose the page to the Ether. (Of course it would show up in the recently edited and other special pages.)

This is more of a webapps.stackexchange.com question though.

Comment: For a new page, you don't need to type a URL - you can also enter the page name into the search field. Then click create.